# Is it good engineering practice to share two different 24 VDC SMPS's neutral wires?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, plc, neutral

Is it good engineering practice to share two different 24 VDC SMPS's neutral wires?

I work in manufacturing with Toshiba extrusion machines which are controlled by PLCs.  Our management wants to add a wireless capability to the process, but we have no more expansion space. They're asking us to add another 24 VDC SMPS to the system and tie the neutral (NOT ground) wires to the existing 24 VDC SMPS's neutral point.

I was always taught that although it is OK to share PE grounds, it is not good engineering practice to share a SMPS 24 VDC neutral wire with another SMPS. Different designs, and primarily improper voltage sensing would occur.  They insist these wires can be connected.

Is this good engineering practice?

Comment: What are the peak DC currents that flow? What gauge wire is to be used? How long is the "shared" connection?

Comment: Thanks for the question Andy.  I'm at 2000mADC using less than 20 feet of 14AWG stranded wire.

Comment: I meant the peak instantaneous current. I wasn't clear. How are the three power supply wires (L1, L2 and N) bundled together i.e. do send and return wires form a low inductance loop due to close proximity? Have you worked out how much volt drop along the common cable can be incurred in one output when pulse currents flow from the other output? This may be ten times worse if the cable loop inductance is not very well defined. How susceptible to interference on power lines are the things that are fed by those power lines? It can be a difficult job to make these calculations of course.

Comment: In other words, it can be "good" (or maybe "reasonable") engineering practise providing that you justify the shared connection with a bunch of calculations.

Comment: Andy:   Thank you.  Fair enough on the calculations.  Looking at the different topologies for various available SMPS's and their DC output sensing/control/regulation schemes, I am getting the sense (no pun intended) that without addressing all of the concerns you have previously mentioned, it is NOT good practice to connect SMPS neutrals.

Comment: I haven't heard of this but I only ever work on small electronic devices, not factories. There's usually no reason why the wire should not be shared inside an electronic device, in fact it is very common to use the same ground (non-protective, i.e. similar to neutral) for every power supply inside a device.

Comment: Phase and neutral wires of one load should go close as possible. If  you share the phase by using 2-wire cable, it is OK.

Comment: Please add a block diagram of the existing setup and the proposed setup: that will make it clear exactly what you mean by "a SMPS 24 VDC neutral wire". I suspect you mean the 0 V rail, but neutral is a term usually used for the mains supply side.

Comment: `share neutral wires` ... isn't that against electrical code?